# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealResponseBody;

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am getting error after building the project like..

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
> Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealResponseBody;
> Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
> Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealResponseBody; Error:   at
> com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
> Error:    at
> com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
> Error:    at
> com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
> Error:    at
> com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
> Error:    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
> Error:    at
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
> Error:    at
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
> Error:    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
> Error:    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
> Error:    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
> Error:    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
> Error:    at
> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
> > Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealResponseBody; Information:BUILD FAILED in
> > 2m 51s Information:15 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See
> > complete output in console

**this is my build gradle file.**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kamran.logingreentheme"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        multiDexEnabled true

        configurations {
            all {
               // exclude module: 'httpclient'
                resolutionStrategy {
                    force 'junit:junit:4.11'
                    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
                }
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/menu'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    //implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
   // implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

**things I have tried**

```
1.clean ,rebuild
2.invalidate catch restart
3.multiplexEnabled **true** also add dependencies:implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

can anyone reslove my error?can anyone explain why i am getting this error??

Comment: is your project override application class?

Comment: @d-feverx no.but i set this-> android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" to my menifest file under application tag

Comment: just try with an application class, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: @d-feverx what if i dont want to override.but i edit my menifest file  to set android:name in the <application> tag as follows:android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Answer (score 0):

Add in `gradle.property` this line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

After that clean and rebuild the project.